# detect circles using cv2.HoughCircles

Tags: python, opencv

i have an image with circles. Sometimes HoughCircles detects these circles and give me what i expect. Other times it doesn't detect, even if the image has circles (so it return me 'None').

the detectCircles(path) function that i am using:

```
img = cv2.imread(path,0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5) 
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,
                        param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
```

I think it could be the way i am using the parameters from the HoughCircle, but i dont understand how can i define these parameters.

I already look on the documentation here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/d53/tutorial_py_houghcircles.html

and here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga47849c3be0d0406ad3ca45db65a25d2d

but it still unclear for me.

The first image HoughCircles doesn't recognize:
http://www.image-share.com/ipng-3711-263.html

Second image that it recognizes only one circle:
http://www.image-share.com/ipng-3711-264.html

Third image that it recognizes perfectly:
http://www.image-share.com/ipng-3711-265.html

Comment: post the original image and the filter result please

Comment: @Micka, i rewrite my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some more information on parameters:

[cvHoughCircles](https://docs.adaptive-vision.com/current/studio/filters/FeatureDetection/cvHoughCircles.html)

- `inImage` - obvious
- `inDp` - resolution multiplier. If you want algorith to be pixel perfect, leave it at '1', but if the image is way too big, you can set it to '2' to make resolution twice as low
- `inMinDist` - minimal distance between circles in pixels. If you're trying to find circles around 100x100 pixel bounding-box size, it'll be reasonable to adjust this value to 20 pixels.
- `inParam1` - canny filter threshold. **It's strongly advised to do some checks on `cvCanny`-ed image to see how to set this threshold properly**. I remember setting it to 200 for nice and bright photographs.
- `inParam2` - how many pixels should be detected to make the circle detected?
- `inMinRadius`/`inMaxRadius` - pretty obvious

To help with `inParam2` look at this image explaining Hough Circles inner working.

[image: Hough Circles]

When you `cvCanny` your image, you get all those white and black pixels. Let's say this white contour on the left is your `cvCanny`-ized circle. Every white pixel is "projecting" circles in varying size. Starts from red circles (minRadius), and goes bigger. The green circles radius is so big all points meet in the middle. The pink point is where 'n' green circles intersect. If 'n' is larger than `inParam2`, the circle is found there.

Comment: Thanks Header! Your answer make things clearer. I'm going to take a look on cvCanny too!